# weibo get status of other user?

Tags: ios, status, timeline, trend, sinaweibo

I want to get the timeline post of the other user using weibo api but not getting.[weibo API](http://open.weibo.com/wiki/API%E6%96%87%E6%A1%A3_V2/en). I am using few API Call like user_timeline,trends but not getting any proper data. please, let me know if I missing any API or any settings in App. I have appKey, secret key and redirect url.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the API calls that would get you this info have all been restricted. The English documentation is not updated, but the chinese documentation specifies for example that you can only use User_timeline to get **your own timeline**, not others.

http://open.weibo.com/wiki/2/statuses/user_timeline
接口升级后：uid与screen_name只能为当前授权用户